# Tic Tac Toe AI - Minimax in C

Tags: c, minimax

I need some help finishing my implementation of Minimax Algorithm for a Tic Tac Toe AI in C.

Particularly, I need help with these 2 functions that do the tree searching and provide the best move, based on its score.
I tried categorising moves as -1 if O wins (human), 1 if X wins (ai) and 0 if its a draw.
When I call the tryMove function with a 1, I mean X is making a move. When I call it with a -1, I mean O is making a move.

For some reason, it places an X in the next cell. Doesn't seem to care about winning or blocking moves, it just does the move in the next cell.

Any help with explanation is greatly appreciated.

```
int tryMove(Board *b, char player){
    int thisScore;
    int score = -2;

    if(won(b) && player == O) return 1;
    else if(won(b)) return -1;
    else if(drawn(b)) return 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(b->cells[i][j] == B){
          b->cells[i][j] = player;
          if(player == X){
            thisScore = tryMove(b, O);
          } else {
            thisScore = tryMove(b, X);
          }
          if(thisScore > score) score = thisScore;
          b->cells[i][j] = B;
        }
      }
    }

    return score;
}

void cpuMove(Board *b){
    int row;
    int col;
    int score = -2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(b->cells[i][j] == B){
          b->cells[i][j] = X;
          int tempScore = tryMove(b, O);
          b->cells[i][j] = B;
          if(tempScore > score){
            score = tempScore;
            row = i;
            col = j;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    b->cells[row][col] = X;
    b->player = O;
    b->moves++;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Saying you *"need help"* is way too broad of a statement (and off-topic for SO)

Comment: Edited, hope I made my problem clearer.

Comment: In the `cpuMove()` function, both variables `row` and `col` are not initialized except when `if(tempScore > score)`.

Comment: Could you add more details when saying **"it places an X in the next cell"** ? What is the meaning of `next cell` ? Because the sensitivity is limited to the range of [-1..+1], a lot of cells could have the maximum score of +1.